# How do you apply the styling of text fetched from the database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I'm creating a blog. In the post page, I am fetching the text from the database, but the styling is not being applied. Instead, I am getting the "raw" output.

I am using `{{post.text}}` to fetch the post content and I am getting:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eget leo cursus, tempus leo non, sodales sem.</p>
```

Instead of the text with the `<p>` styling.

I am using django-ckeditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my self in case someone looks for the same.

You just need to add `|safe` to the text loop. So it becomes `{{post.text|safe}}`.